# Getting post id in for loop

Tags: loop

I have an existing for loop, which is necessary for the design and layout. Inside this for loop I need show post by post.

This is my code.

```
<?php for($i=$val;$i<=$cdn;$i++) { ?>
<div class="desc dsc<?php echo $dsc++; ?>" style="display: none">
    <div class="team-details">
        <div class="name">
            <?php echo get_the_title();?><span><?php the_field('designation'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'content'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I need to get each post inside this for loop without affecting the structure. Please help

This is my full page code

```
<?php //Template Name: File get_header(); get_template_part( 'weblizar', 'breadcrumbs'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="title wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">Meet our Team</h2>
    <div class="content team-content wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'content'); endwhile; else : get_template_part( 'nocontent'); endif; get_template_part( 'post-author'); ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php //comments_template( '',true); ?>
        <div class="clearfix mar_top2"></div>
    </div>
    <section>
        <div class="team-list-wrapper clearfix wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <!-- Set Category Name to Portfolio-Item -->
            <?php query_posts( array ( 'post_type'=>'our-team', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
            <!-- Start WordPress Loop -->
            <?php $count=0; $dsc=0 ; $ids=0 ; ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ($count==0) : ?>
            <ul id="co-team">
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($ids==3) : $val=0 ; $cdn=3 ; endif; ?>
                <?php if ($ids==7) : $val=3 ; $cdn=6 ; endif; ?>
                <?php if ($ids==11) : $val=7 ; $cdn=10; endif; ?>
                <?php if ($ids>11) : $val = 11; $cdn =14; endif; ?>
                <li class="nav team-list">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id());?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title();?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title();?>">
                    <div class="hover-item ids<?php echo $ids++; ?>">
                        <div class="actv-desc">
                            <div class="team-details">
                                <div class="name">
                                    <?php echo get_the_title();?><span><?php the_field('designation'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'content'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php $id=g et_field( 'facebook'); $id1=g et_field( 'twitter'); $id2=g et_field( 'linkedin'); $id3=g et_field( 'gplus'); $id4=g et_field( 'youtube'); if(!empty($id) || !empty($id1) || !empty($id2) || !empty($id3) || !empty($id4) ) { ?>
                            <div class="social-medias-holder">
                                <ul class="social-medias">
                                    <?php if( get_field( 'facebook') ): ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_field('facebook'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if( get_field( 'twitter') ): ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_field('twitter'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if( get_field( 'linkedin') ): ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_field('linkedin'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if( get_field( 'gplus') ): ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_field('gplus'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if( get_field( 'youtube') ): ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php the_field('youtube'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php $count++; ?>
                <?php if ($count==4 ||$wp_query->found_posts==0) : ?>
                <?php $count=0; ?>
            </ul>
            <style>
                .desc{
                    background: #000;
                   }
            </style>
            <?php echo $cdn; for($i=$val;$i<=$cdn;$i++) { ?>
            <div class="desc dsc<?php echo $dsc++; ?>" style="display: none">
                <?php echo $post_id; ?>
                <div class="team-details">
                    <div class="name">
                        <?php echo get_the_title($post_id);?><span><?php the_field('designation',$post_id); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'content'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
    </section>
</div>
<div id="foot-btn">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hi-icon-wrap hi-icon-effect-6 " title="Join FIFI"> <a href="http://www.studiofifi.com/careers/" id="open-event" class="hi-icon hi-icon-contract ">Contract</a>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow_box"> <a href="http://www.studiofifi.com/careers/" class="up-arrow"> Join FIFI</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
       animation: 'grow',
       delay: 200,
       theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
       trigger: 'hover'
    });


    $('.ids0').click(function() {  $('.dsc0').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids1').click(function() {  $('.dsc1').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids2').click(function() {  $('.dsc2').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids3').click(function() {  $('.dsc3').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids4').click(function() {  $('.dsc4').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids5').click(function() {  $('.dsc5').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids6').click(function() {  $('.dsc6').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids7').click(function() {  $('.dsc7').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids8').click(function() {  $('.dsc8').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids9').click(function() {  $('.dsc9').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids10').click(function() {  $('.dsc10').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids11').click(function() {  $('.dsc11').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids12').click(function() {  $('.dsc12').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids13').click(function() {  $('.dsc13').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids14').click(function() {  $('.dsc14').toggle( "slow" );   });
    $('.ids15').click(function() {  $('.dsc15').toggle( "slow" );   });
    //         
          });
</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to get the post id to say add it to a div use the_ID()

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the toggle-able code inside the main loop; put it inside the `hover-item` div. Get rid of all of the counting variables - $dsc, $ids, $cdn. Something like this:

```
<li class="nav team-list">
    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id());?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title();?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title();?>">
    <div class="hover-item ids">
        <div class="actv-desc">
            <div class="team-details">
                <div class="name">
                    <?php echo get_the_title();?><span><?php the_field('designation'); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'content'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="social-medias-holder">
                <!-- this stuff -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="desc" style="display: none">
            <div class="team-details">
                <div class="name">
                    <?php echo get_the_title();?><span><?php the_field('designation'); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php get_template_part( 'post', 'content'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Change the class for the .hover-item.ids1 (ect) to not have a number on it, just:

```
<div class="hover-item ids">
```

Update the script at the bottom to get rid of all the repeated stuff, and rewrite it like this:

```
$('.ids').click(function() { 
    var $toggleable = $(this).find('.desc');
    $toggleable.toggle( "slow" );
});
```

You'll probably need to change how your css styles work because of how the html structure is changing.

Comment: Doesn't help me to get the layout I need. I need the first row(4 posts) to show the description in the second row(common description area).

Comment: It can be done using this markup, absolutely. That's a css question though. You don't need to get the post id or use a second loop to display a second row of information just under the first.

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate the number you're 'echoing' from the loop. here's an example from a recent site I've built:

```
<?php $startnum = 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 2 ) );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="section-number-<?php echo $startnum; ?>">

  <h1>the_title()</h1>
  <div>the_content()</div>

</div>
<?php 
$startnum++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```